# SQL report that includes sales rep, sales rep's state, and the total sales for that sales rep's state ordered by YYY-MM

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

**The situation.** I am trying to make a report that lists the sales rep names (all of them; there are 50), the sales rep's state, and the total sales broken down by YYYY-MM for that state. If there are two or more sales reps in the state, they should each be listed with the same information for their state. How the final list is ordered does not matter, so long as all the information is included.

**The problem.** I also need totals by state in addition to the totals I have.

Here is my code:

```
 SELECT
    dim_sales_rep.sales_rep_name as 'Sales Rep',
    dim_state.abbreviation as 'State',
    date_format(dim_date.date, '%Y-%m') as 'Year-Month',
    concat('$',sum(fact_sales.total_sales)) as 'Sales'
FROM
    (
        (
            dim_sales_rep
        JOIN dim_state ON dim_sales_rep.state_key = dim_state.state_key
        )
    JOIN fact_sales ON dim_sales_rep.sales_rep_key = fact_sales.sales_rep_key
    )
JOIN dim_date ON fact_sales.date_key = dim_date.date_key
GROUP BY dim_date.year, dim_date.month, dim_state.abbreviation, dim_sales_rep.sales_rep_name
```

Sample Output:

```
Rep             State       Year-Month      Sales
Michele Harris   GA          2010-08         $679.79
T.S. Eliot       GA          2010-07         $2938.74
```

It should look like this:

```
Rep             State       Year-Month      Sales
Michele Harris   GA          2010-08         $679.79
Georgiana Woe    GA          2010-08         $482.98
State total                                  $1162.77
```

Or like this:

```
Rep             State      Year-Month      YM Total      State Total
Michaele Harris GA         2010-08         $679.79       $1162.77
Georgiana Woe   GA         2010-08         $482.98       $1162.77
```

Here is the data structure:

> **table fact_sales**
>
> date_key (PK) Surrogate Key
>
> account_key (PK)  Surrogate Key
>
> sales_rep_key (PK)    Surrogate Key
>
> total_sales   Total sales dollars.
>
> count_of_products Number of products sold
>
> **table dim_state**
>
> state_key (PK)    Surrogate Key
>
> abbreviation  e.g. AL or CA
>
> name  e.g. California
>
> **table dim_account**
>
> account_key (PK)  Surrogate Key
>
> account_name
>
> account_address
>
> state_key Surrogate Key
>
> effective_date    Starting date that this record is active
>
> expiration_date   Ending date that this record is active
>
> is_current    Represents the active record
>
> **table dim_sales_rep**
>
> sales_rep_key (PK)    Surrogate Key
>
> sales_rep_name
>
> state_key     Surrogate Key
>
> effective_date    Starting date that this record is active
>
> expiration_date   Ending date that this record is active
>
> is_current    Represents the active record
>
> **table dim_date**
>
> date_key (PK) Surrogate Key      date e.g. 2011-01-01
>
> month e.g. 01
>
> year  e.g. 2011

Notes:

PK: Denotes that the column is the primary key or is part of the primary key of the table.

Surrogate Keys are represented as numeric and do not represent actual values from an application. For example date_key could be 1,2,3,4, etc. and is not a real date.

Assume that dim_date contains all dates for all time.

Assume that if the column has the same name in a different table that they are equivalent.

Comment: Massively simplify the problem, and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You are using MySQL's non-standard extension to `GROUP BY`. Please read [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html). Your query is likely to yield unpredictable results.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a 3-column surrogate PK.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Do not put date in a dimension table; leave it intact (`DATE` datatype) in the main table.

Comment: I was handed the data structure but not the data, I'm afraid. By "surrogate" I believe it is a foreign key.

Comment: I just solved some of the problems and put an edited version of the problem up. I hope it's simpler.

Answer (score 1):

When you group by just the state, you get one row per state in your result set. That's what `GROUP BY` means: aggregate your data broken out by the column values it mentions.

Use this:

```
GROUP BY dim_date.year, dim_date.month, dim_state.abbreviation, dim_sales_rep.sales_rep_name WITH ROLLUP
```

And, formatting your dates well can be done using MySQL's date functions.

Try this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-',2014,3,1),'%Y-%m-%e'),'%Y-%m')
```

Comment: Thanks. I used DATE_FORMAT on my date field (dim_date.date) and was able to get the output I wanted for that column. See edited post.

Comment: The GROUP BY is  so close! It gives the total sales for each salesperson in each state.  Now to get the totals by state in addition and it will be perfect. Thanks!